# new line on plantuml

Tags: diagram, sequence-diagram, plantuml

I've this plantUml

```
@startuml
!$user = {
           "name": "John Doe",
           "email": "john@gmail.com",
           "points": 100,
           "language": "en",
           "settings": {
             "notifications": {
               "email": true,
               "push": true,
               "sms": false
             }
           },
           "role": "user",
           "premiumId": "premiumId"
         }

HomePage -> HomePage: show loader
HomePage -> UserEndPoint : GET /user and check the user permissions
HomePage <-- UserEndPoint : $user
HomePage -> UserFriendsEndPoint : GET /user/friends
HomePage -> UserMentorsEndPoint : GET /user/mentors
HomePage -> UserGoalsEndPoint : GET /user/goals
HomePage -> ContentEndPoint : GET /content
```

and down below is how it's displayed.

[image]

How can I format the user data like is in the editor?

I tried to

```
!$user = {
           "name": "John Doe\n",
           "email": "john@gmail.com\n",
           "points": 100,
           "language": "en",
           "settings": {
             "notifications": {
               "email": true,
               "push": true,
               "sms": false
             }
           },
           "role": "user",
           "premiumId": "premiumId"
         }
```

But with this, the diagram is displayed like down below

[image]

I tried

`"name": "John Doe"\n`

or

`"name": "John Doe",\n`

but both throw me an error.

How can I format like

```
{
           "name": "John Doe",
           "email": "john@gmail.com",
           "points": 100,
           "language": "en",
           "settings": {
             "notifications": {
               "email": true,
               "push": true,
               "sms": false
             }
           },
           "role": "user",
           "premiumId": "premiumId"
         }
```

right now I'm using [plantuml for webstorm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration)

Comment: It's a great question for forum.plantuml.net I think. I would suggest asking for a `<style>` feature that could apply to JSON on messages like this, maybe `linewrap true` or something. Otherwise, you could force the order of the participants (declare the order of `participant XYZ`) so that `EndUserPoint` is the rightmost, but it's still quite a gap with that long JSON line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON format is probably most useful for diagramming JSON objects. You don't have to use it on a message (although I understand why you did). If all you want is a message for a sequence diagram, you can format it by hand:

```
@startuml
Bob -> Alice : {\n  "name": "John Doe",\n  "email": "john@gmail.com"\n}
@enduml
```

[image]

ETA: With many editors (webstorm?) you have the "join" function that will combine multiple lines into one. Then you only have to add the `\n`'s in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

....Links to the rescue:

@startuml

Bob -> Alice : [[{\n  "name": "John Doe",\n  "email": "john@gmail.com"\n} Message]]

@enduml

this will produce a tooltip on hover over with the message-content in it. May also help to keep your diagrams tidy....

caveat:only works in SVG diagrams